# How to install 'x2goserver' and 'x2goserver-xsession' on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.10

I am trying to install x2go server on a remote machine with Ubuntu 14.10.
This is how I try to do it:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:x2go/stable
apt-get update
apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
```

It was all going well until the last code line, and it outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package x2goserver-xsession is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package x2goserver is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'x2goserver' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'x2goserver-xsession' has no installation candidate
```

I just want to connect the remote machine by using x2goclient which is installed on my personal computer.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you find an answer?